# How to score adding a Perl library on the command line?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring

I know the Perl `-p` flag is counted as one byte. I've just added the Perl bignum library to my answer to make it shorter. I'm using it like this: `perl -p -Mbignum filename.pl`. How many bytes does it count as?

Answer (score 3):

People usually count `-p` as one byte because `perl -pE` has a distance of 1 to `perl -E` (arguably the default). If you require reading the source code from a file for some reason, `-p` would count as three bytes, as `perl -p file.pl` has a distance of 3 to `perl file.pl`.

Likewise, `perl -p -Mbignum file.pl` has a distance of 9 to `perl -p file.pl`, so it comes at a 9 byte score penalty.